# Custom theme function not being called?

Tags: 7, theming, hooks, entities

I'm building a Drupal 7 module to create a bespoke field type. I've implemented all the required hooks. My `hook_field_formatter_view()` function looks like this:

```
function MYMODULE_field_formatter_view($entity_type, $entity, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $display) {
  $element = array();

  switch ($display['type']) {
    case 'default':
      foreach ($items as $delta => $item) {
                $element[$delta] = array(
                  '#theme' => 'test',
                  '#item' => $item,
                );
      }
      break;
  }

  return $element;  
}
```

I've then defined the `theme()` function below:

```
function theme_test($variables) {
    return '<h1>Hello World</h1>';
}
```

But when I view the page nothing is output. If I look at the recent log entries I see this message:

`Theme key 'test' not found.`

If I change my MYMODULE_field_formatter_view render array '#theme' value to a built in theme function like 'item_list' it works. But for some reason my custom theme function is not being picked up.

I've rebuilt the theme registry hundreds of times as well as cleared the caches.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You probably have not defined your theme hook in `hook_theme()`.

The [Using the theme layer](http://drupal.org/node/933976) section of the Development handbook has an in-depth discussion about this.

Comment: Spot on, I keep getting caught out by these little changes from Drupal 6 to Drupal 7!

Comment: Theme functions must be registered too in Drupal 6.

Answer (score 10):

You need to define the theme function in [`hook_theme`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7) and then clear the cache.

```
 function MYMODULE_theme() {
   return array(
     'test' => array (
       'render element' => 'element',
     ),
   );
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue where my custom theme function was never being called in my template, even though it was registered. When I switched to another theme, it worked.

My solution was re-naming theme into 'something_theme', because I made a stupid mistake and already had module named 'something'.

**Module and theme should never have the same name**, because it leads into collision which causes unexpected behavior and hook overriding.